# extracting values to be populated in a dropdown from SQLite database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC and using FluentNHibernate for ORM.
I am faced with a situation.

I have 8 tables say A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H and each table has say 10 attributes, out of which an average of 5 are lists that have to be populated as dropdowns in the view.

Now, these values have to be extracted from the database. I have built individual tables for each dropdown attribute in table A with values, say HighestEducation is an attribute in A and the dropdown values include Undergrad, Masters, Doctorate, etc.

I want to build a tightly coupled ADO.NET entity model for that table, but cant seem to do so. Any suggestions on how to get around this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assuming

class Person
{
    public virtual Education HighestEducation { get; set; }
}

class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        References(p => p.HighestEducation);
    }
}
```

then either eager fetch when querying

```
var persons = session.Query<Person>()
    .Where(...)
    .Fetch(p => p.HighestEducation)
    .Fetch(p => p.LikelyHoodToFly)
    .Fetch(p => p.LikelyHoodToExplode)
    .Fetch(p => p.SomethingElseType)
    .List();
```

or load them all using futures (one roundtrip) and rely on the first level cache

```
session.Query<Education>().Future();
session.Query<SomeThingElse>().Future();
session.Query<LikelyHood>().Future();
var persons = session.Get<Person>().Where(...).Future();
```